# Создание динамической таблицы

Tags: c++, qt

пытаюсь создать таблицу с тремя столбцами:

| First | Secont | Third |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2.6 | 1.4 | 4.0 |
| 1.2 |  | 1.2 |
|  |  | 0 |
|  | 7.9 | 7.9 |

При заполнении пользователем первых двух ячеек в одной строке, появляется их сумма в третьей.

Вопрос по реализации - возможно сделать это через QTableWidget + слоты/сигналы или же требуется иной инструмент для этого? Просто на данный момент сильно забуксовал на моменте создания сигналов при изменении значения в ячейке, появляются мысли, что выбрал не тот путь для реализации или же просто неверно соединяю сигналы со слотами:

```
void MainWindow::createUi(qint8 Lines,QStringList headers){
ui->tableWidget->setColumnCount(3);
ui->tableWidget->setRowCount(Lines);

for (int i=1;i==Lines; i++)
{
    connect (&ui, ui->tableWidget->cellChanged(i,1),
             this, getEmptyCapWeight());
}}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: да, возможно, но в `connect()`'е у тебя какая-то несуразица написана...

Comment: Это можно сделать и в QTableWidget и в QTableView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

начнем с вашего цикла

```
for (int i=1;i==Lines; i++)
```

даже если бы он был нужен, в таком виде он не будет работать от слова совсем.

Теперь непосредственно о сигналах-слотах.

Коннекты прописываются [в старом или в новом синтаксисе](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax/ru) Чаще всего имеет следующий вид:

```
connect(object1, SIGNAL(signalname(...)), object2, SLOT(slotname(...)))
```

где:

- **object1** - объект, генерирующий сигнал (в вашем случае это таблица
  ui->tableWidget)
- **signalname(...)** - сигнатура сигнала (в вашем случае
  сигнал cellChanged(int, int))
- **object2** - объект, содержащий слот,
  которым будет обрабатываться сигнал (в вашем случае это само главное
  окно, т.е. this)
- **slotname(...)** - сигнатура слота (функция - член
  класса принимающего объекта, прописываемая в заголовочном файле в
  секции SLOTS: вашего класса. При этом сигнатура слота и сигнала должны совпадать)

Теперь можно написать коннект правильно (обращаю внимание что цикл не нужен):

```
connect(ui->tableWidget, SIGNAL(cellChanged(int, int)), this, SLOT(mySlot(int,int)))
```

и обработать сигнал в своем слоте:

```
void MainWindow::mySlot(int row, int col){
   if(col>1) return; // обрабатывать вам надо только изменение в столбцах 0 и 1
   int val_0 = ui->tableWidget->item(row,0)->text().toInt();
   int val_1 = ui->tableWidget->item(row,1)->text().toInt();
   ui->tableWidget->item(row, 2)->setText(QString("%1").arg(val_0+val_1));
}
```

Comment: s/toInt/toDouble/ только...

Comment: По коннекту - стараюсь уйти от старого синтаксиса. Спасибо за ответ! Я уж думал каждую ячейку нужно будет связывать.